# All parts of array becomming the same

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating a program that will ad a number to an array that is equal to 1 over the number of the past array. The wanted output is: `[[13],[12],[11],[10]]` but the output from this program is`[[13],[13],[13],[13]]` do you know how I can fix the code to show the wanted output? Program is below

```
var test = [[10]]
intervalID = setInterval(function(){
   var test_first = test[0];
   test_first[0] += 1;
   test.unshift(test_first);
   console.log(test);
},1000);
```

Comment: You have to build a new array on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the same array object to the array repeatedly. Instead clone:

```
var test_first = [ ...test[0] ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are manipulating the value `test_first`, and you are implicitly stringifying the value in `test[0][0]` by accessing `test[0]` - which returns an array of a single number, not a number. The code that produces what your requirement is would be

```js
const test = [[10]]
const intervalID = setInterval(() =>{
    const new_val = test[0][0] + 1;
    test.unshift([new_val]);
    console.log(test);
},1000);
```

I'm pretty sure you're looking for an array of numbers like `[13, 12, 11, 10]`. That's produced by below code

```js
const test = [10]
const intervalID = setInterval(() =>{
    const new_val = test[0] + 1;
    test.unshift(new_val);
    console.log(test);
},1000);
```